# moving images on hover with css

Tags: css, image, hover, move

is it possible tho have this hover effect http://apotheke-hh.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=11&Itemid=2
with css, working in all major browsers?

For others who read this and if the link is broken - see attached images.

Regards
Torsten!
[image: hover image two]

[hover image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwFIh.png)

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Hi Paulie - I understand CSS but not JS. The result here is a very useful answer, that uses less code and is a contemporary solution, that can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can for all major browsers, but it depends on the versions of course, here is an example:

HTML

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="col one"></div>
    <div class="col two"></div>
    <div class="col three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col {
   float:left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 150px;
    transition:width 300ms ;
}

.all:hover .col{
    width:25%;
}
.all:hover .col:hover {
    width: 50%;
}
```

and the live on on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/mrXPu/

The only 'weird' rule is `transition` which has a very good support as seen in [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavlos - that is exact what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you'll need JS to achieve this effect! CSS only solution isn't possible in all major browsers.